# Can I update firebase database without synching local?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to update the firebase database without retrieving a json object that then updates my local store?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that comes to mind is to call the REST API. Anything using the SDK will also update the local cache.